# Need explanation on the solution of a combinatorics problem involving squares with parallel sides

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation

Let a finite number of squares with parallel sides in the plane, such that if any $k+1$ squares are chosen, then there exist $2$ intersecting squares among them. Prove that the squares can be grouped into $2k-1$ sets such that any two squares in the same set intersect.

I found this problem on AOPS, but I couldn't understand the solution.

https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h1805602p12209708

This is the link. I couldn't understand properly why "Squares that do intersect with $ABCD$ either contains point $B$ or point $C$ or both." (as it is written in the last comment to the post). Can you please enlighten me? Or if the problem is wrong, could you please help me with a counterexample? Thank you so much!

[Need counterexample on a combinatorics problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3923791/need-counterexample-on-a-combinatorics-problem)

Comment: Your restatement is a little off: the original problem says "all squares in the same group have a common point", which is stronger than "any two squares in the same [group] intersect".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the additional assumption in the question as posed on AoPS that the squares are all congruent; without loss of generality we may take the side length as $1$. $ABCD$ is, in the solution provided there, (one of) the leftmost squares in the collection; say that its lower-left corner has coordinates $(x,y)$. Then any square $S$ intersecting $ABCD$ must have lower-left corner $(u,v)$ where $x\le u\le x+1$ (since $ABCD$ is the leftmost square) and $y-1\le v\le y+1$.

It is easy to show that if $y-1\le v\le y$ then $S$ contains $C$; if $y\le v\le y+1$ then $S$ contains $B$. Thus $S$ will always contain at least one of $B$ and $C$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Could you please say anything about the same question but ignoring the fact that the squares are congruent? Would the problem still be true?

Comment: What would the problem be if $S$ is contained in $ABCD$?

Comment: Sure. But I asked if the problem would be true, not if the proof would work. I'm sorry for writing again. Could you please give me a counterexample of some noncongruent squares such that the conditions in the problem are fulfilled, but the conclusion isn't true? Thank you so much. Sorry for disturbing you again

Comment: @furfur Please ask that as another question.

Comment: Fine. Thank you for the answer in the case the squares are congruent.